# How can I add an image at a specific X, Y location using Perl's PDF::API2?

Tags: perl, pdf

I'm using Perl's [PDF::API2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PDF-API2) module to create a PDF document and I need to add an PNG image at a specific X,Y location on the page.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Actually I worked it out:

```
# grab a text object - we are missing fonts?
my $gfx = $page->gfx;

my $image = $self->pdf->image_png('/tmp/logo.png');

# add the image to the graphic object - x, y, width, height  
$gfx->image($image, 24, 815, 102, 29);
```